# RequireJS - make plugin a default loader

Tags: requirejs, reactjs

Our codebase is going to be gradually moved towards React framework, using the incredible JSX Transformer.

JSX Transformer is idempotent for ordinary Javascript files and transpile JSX dialect into Javascript. As such, I would like to avoid having to write 'jsx!' in front of every single dependency - I would like JSX to be the **default** loader for RequireJS.

Is this possible in RequireJS?

Comment: As an alternative, precompile your modules using the jsx command line tool (I don't know require.js, but that seems like the simplest solution).

Comment: I worked on this problem for a while where I work and have not been able to find an easy way to do this while still reaping the benefits of RequireJS' dev-time tooling. We are considering switching to a webpack-based build system.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compile all your React files with grunt + browserify + reactify. Here is basic grunt config to do it:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) { 'use strict';

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    // Task configuration goes here.
    paths: {},
    browserify: {
      options: {
        transform: ['reactify'],
      },
      dev: {
        src: '<%= paths.src_js %>/app/app.jsx',
        dest: '<%= paths.build_js %>/app.js',
        options: { debug: true }
      },
      prod: {
        src: '<%= browserify.dev.src %>',
        dest: '<%= paths.build_js %>/app.min.js',
        options: { debug: false },
      }
    },
    watch: {
      options: { livereload: true },
      browserify: {
        files: ['<%= paths.src_js %>/app/**/*'],
        tasks: ['browserify:dev'],
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

  grunt.registerTask('dev',  ['browserify:dev']);
  grunt.registerTask('prod',  ['browserify:prod']);
};
```

You run it by `grunt dev` or `grunt prod`.

Comment: This is a solution we used eventually - for a production build. Doing this for daily development work is somewhat unwieldy - your front-end will not update if the watch task is not running. Sometimes watch + compile is somewhat slow and doesn't finish compiling by the time you reload the page.

Comment: I'm using it for both development and production. grunt watch right now takes around 1.5sec and browser autoreloads when build is done with livereload plugin. I hit some issues to make grunt watch quick and making multiple isolated watch tasks to compile only necessary files did a trick.